# Web service cast exception why?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exception, serialization

```
Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

The above error is caused when I call a method to a  web service

```
List<string> bob = myService.GetAllList();
```

Where: GetAllList =

```
[WebMethod]
        public List<string> GetAllList()
        {

            List<string> list ....
            return list;
        }
```

I have rebuilt the whole solution, updated the service references and still I get a cast exception any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to do this:

```
List<string> bob = new List<string>(myService.GetAllList());
```

An overload for the constructor of a generic list takes an IEnumerable of the specified type to initialize the array.  You can not, like the exception states, implicitly cast it staright to that type.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP protocol doesn't support generic collections.

Try this instead:

```
List<string> bob = new List<string>(myService.GetAllList());
```